# Android Google maps throw nullpointerexception during initialization

Tags: android, google-maps

Hey I'm trying to implement goole maps fragment to a tabs fragment. The tabhost is also another fragment inside an fragmentactivity with a navigation drawer here is my current code I am getting a null pointer exception at the initialization of the map

```
package com.shimba.android.secure.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.shimba.android.secure.R;
import com.shimba.android.secure.http.NetworkConnectionStatus;
import com.shimba.android.secure.http.RestClient;

public class LocationFragment extends Fragment
        implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener,
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private static View v;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    Location location;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    Polyline polyLine;
    protected LatLng start;
    String distance, duration;
    Marker marker2;
    protected LatLng end;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    ArrayList<Marker> mArrayMarkers;
    List<Double> listDistance;

    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        if (v != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(v);
        }
        try {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
           // if (NetworkConnectionStatus.isOnline(getActivity())) {
             //   new GetPlacesTask().execute();
            //}
        } catch (InflateException e) {
         /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mLocationClient != null) {
            mLocationClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (map == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (map != null) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(
                    getActivity(),
                    this,  // ConnectionCallbacks
                    this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
        }
    }

    public void showMyLocation(View view) {
        if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            String msg = "Location = " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hating me", 155000).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        return false;
    }


    public class GetPlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url = null;
            try {
                url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%20-1.296436,36.791540&keyword=safaricom+shop&rankby=distance&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBVwYvGApeZmrPCTilzMKgpk5Hr48TisbM";
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String json = "{}";
            try {
                json = RestClient.makeRestRequest(RestClient.GET, url, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("ShopPlaces", json);
            editor.commit();
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //System.out.println(result);


        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

error log looks like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.shimba.android.secure.fragments.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:92)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:283)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1233)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1029)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4356)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4747)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the full error stack trace.

Comment: @user3249477 I've posted the log

Comment: Currently it's showing that a commented line is throwing the NPE. Please update your code and/or log.

Comment: @user3249477 hey I had edited the code try now but now I've posted all of it